Unrecognized Manifest option
I'm using MSVC 2017 on Windows 8.1.
During the compilation I'm getting the following error:

c:\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\wx_dpi_aware_pmv2.manifest : manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "dpiAwareness" in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings

What is the problem here? Was DPIAwareness removed from being used in the manifest?
Thank you

Your tooling is getting outdated.  dpiAwareness was made available in Windows 10, version 1607, released in April 2018

@HansPassant, so what do I do? Ignore it? Will my binary work under different DPI?

'dpiAwareness' is only available on Windows 10 1607 and above and you are working on Windows 8.1.'DpiAware' is available starting from Windows Vista but it has limits and can only set to true or pm.
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Understood. Thx. Will ignore for now...
